# Auto generated code flagging errors in VB.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a VB.Net project in visual studio 2010 intended to let a user upload a video and then stick it in a DB. The file is called "Media/Test.aspx.vb".

When I tried to run the code to debug, tons of errors were generated for a file called App_Web_nkhy2w0y.0.vb

I couldn't locate this file anywhere, and I certainly didn't write it, so I double clicked on the error and it opened a file with about 350 lines of (apparently) auto-generated code, and I have no clue what I did to cause it to do this. Nor do I have any idea how to fix it.

I'll admit I'm new to VB.Net, but I've never seen anything like this online so I'm in the dark.

My original code is below for the code-behind file that handles nothing more than a fileupload control, button, and label in the actual page.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Partial Class Media_Test

Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Protected Sub TryMe_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TryMe.Click
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    'check the file
    Dim buffer As Byte()

    If testFile.HasFile AndAlso testFile.PostedFile IsNot Nothing AndAlso testFile.PostedFile.FileName <> "" Then
        Dim file As HttpPostedFile = testFile.PostedFile
        'retrieve the HttpPostedFile object

        buffer = New Byte(file.ContentLength - 1) {}
        Dim bytesReaded As Integer = file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, testFile.PostedFile.ContentLength)
        'the HttpPostedFile has InputStream porperty (using System.IO;)
        'which can read the stream to the buffer object,
        'the first parameter is the array of bytes to store in,
        'the second parameter is the zero index (of specific byte)
        'where to start storing in the buffer,
        'the third parameter is the number of bytes 
        'you want to read (do u care about this?)

        If bytesReaded > 0 Then
            Try
                Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
                connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Videos (Video, Video_Name, Video_Size)" & " VALUES (@video, @videoName, @videoSize)", connection)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@video", SqlDbType.VarBinary, buffer.Length).Value = buffer
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@videoName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = testFile.FileName
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@videoSize", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = file.ContentLength
                Using connection
                    connection.Open()
                    Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Label1.Text = "uploaded, " & i.ToString() & " rows affected"
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                Label1.Text = ex.Message.ToString()
            End Try

        End If
    Else
        Label1.Text = "Choose a valid video file"
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

And the top of the generated page is:

```
#ExternalChecksum("C:\Users\handcm\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\APPS\Media\Test.aspx","{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}","F31F20662F14B4894B6FBF58215628CB")
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.296
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can post the entire file if need be, but could someone shine some light on what's going on here? I have no clue how to debug a file I didn't write or have never seen.

Edit 2: I checked the "'InitializeCulture' is not a member of 'ASP.media_test_aspx" error and it usually is a discrepancy between the class being inherited on the aspx page not being the correct as in the aspx.vb file. However, in this case, there isn't a discrepancy as it's the correct file.

Edit: Some of the error messages I am getting:

- Error 4   'GetWrappedFileDependencies' is not a member of 'ASP.media_test_aspx'.  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\apps\f1b28c0f\bab8f810\App_Web_nkhy2w0y.0.vb  103
- Error 2   Class 'media_test_aspx' must implement 'ReadOnly Property IsReusable As Boolean' for interface 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'. Implementing property must have matching 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifiers.    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\apps\f1b28c0f\bab8f810\App_Web_nkhy2w0y.0.vb  84
- Error 10  'ProcessRequest' is not a member of 'Media_Test'.   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\apps\f1b28c0f\bab8f810\App_Web_nkhy2w0y.0.vb  342
- Error 1   'InitializeCulture' is not a member of 'ASP.media_test_aspx'.   C:\Users\handcm\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\APPS\Media\Test.aspx  1
  I don't even know what the last one is referring to, as there is definitely not an "Initialize Culture" on the page.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: I editted the post to include several.